# PyTorch equivalent of `numpy.unpackbits`?

Tags: pytorch

I am training a neural net on GPU. It uses a lot of binary input features.

Since moving data to/from GPU is expensive, I am looking for ways to make the initial representation more compact. Now, I encode my features as **int8**, move them over to GPU and *then* expand as **float32**:

```py
# create int8
features = torch.zeros(*dims, dtype=torch.int8)

# fill in some data (set some features to 1.)
…

# move int8 to GPU
features = features.to(device=cuda, non_blocking=True)

# expand int8 as float32
features = features.to(dtype=float32)
```

Now, I am looking for ways to compress those binary features to bits instead of bytes.

NumPy has functions [`packbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) and [`unpackbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html)

```py
>>> a = np.array([[2], [7], [23]], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> b = np.unpackbits(a, axis=1)
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Is there any way to unpack bits in PyTorch on GPU?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DLPack to convert your Pytorch tensor to CuPy array, then use `cupy.unpackbits`:

```
import cupy
import torch

from torch.utils.dlpack import to_dlpack
from torch.utils.dlpack import from_dlpack

# Create a PyTorch tensor.
tx = torch.cuda.ByteTensor([1, 2, 3, 4])

# Convert it into a DLPack tensor.
dx = to_dlpack(tx)

# Convert it into a CuPy array.
cx = cupy.fromDlpack(dx)

# Unpack bits (does not support axis, so flatten/reshape as needed)
cx_bits = cupy.unpackbits(cx).reshape(-1, 8)

# Convert it back to a PyTorch tensor.
tx_bits = from_dlpack(cx_bits.toDlpack())
```

UPDATE: I'm not actually sure DLPack is necessary:

```
>>> t = torch.cuda.ByteTensor([[2], [22], [222]])
>>> t_bits = torch.as_tensor(cupy.unpackbits(cupy.asarray(t)).reshape(-1, 8), device="cuda")
>>>
>>> t_bits
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no similar functions at the time of writing this answer. However, a workaround is using [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.from_numpy) as in:

```
In[2]: import numpy as np
In[3]: a = np.array([[2], [7], [23]], dtype=np.uint8)
In[4]: b = np.unpackbits(a, axis=1)
In[5]: b
Out[5]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
In[6]: import torch
In[7]: torch.from_numpy(b)
Out[7]: 
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Comment: Yes, but NumPy works on CPU, while I was looking for a GPU solution.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that, apologies. However, I do not see any operation that favors the GPU (that my point of view, feel free to take it or leave it) : )